# Google Plus Share ihgnores open graph Meta and itemprops

Tags: facebook-opengraph, rich-snippets

I use a google plus share button on a site.
Usually it accepts the given meta Data. All the data I send, are accepted. Only the description gets ignored.

I have placed it in this way:

```
<meta itemprop="description" content="text text text" />
<meta property='og:description' content="text text text"/>
```

In the document's head. I did it that way on many site and it worked fine.
Today I installed the button and tested it and it did not work anymore.

I also testet it on other sites, where I installed it earlier and where know, that it worked (tested it).
The same result: instead of the description, the document's link is getting shared.

Did Google change anything?
What could be the error?

The rich snippet Tool as well as the opengraph testing tool, show the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, although the badge seems to work just fine. Wondering what could it be. Try checking the badge. although it does look like a google problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `<meta name="og:description or description" content="Your desc"/>` instead of "itemprop" and "property" ?

Answer (score 0):

og:description is for facebook, itemprop for google+, i used it before and without changing the script it stopped working for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

`og:description` is used for google plus and linkedin, along with others.

`itemprop` is structured data, which google will use if present (and is likely to prefer to meta tags). But - it does not work on its own. It must be nested within code containing the type of schema, it does not know from this line is your description is for the page, a product you are selling, a movie, etc. Normally you put structured data in the body and nest it inside a body, div or other tag, see http://schema.org/WebPage for examples,

```
<body itemcope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <meta itemprop="description" content="Your desc"/>
  <meta itemprop="url" content="http://example.com/page1"/>
```