# Google Plus Share does not take description

Tags: php, google-plus, facebook-opengraph, social-media

I am using OG protocol for google sharing.

Added below meta-tags in < head > tag.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://goo.gl/oUpJs1" />
<meta property="og:title" content="SA Test Lesson 14092015 04" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="TappnEd" />
<meta property="og:description" content="this is description." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://a35080557e7a03b9f1f1-86aee789662273f4e4ffb1bc62c5c3ee.r62.cf3.rackcdn.com/11442230240.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="320" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="240" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

When I hit https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://goo.gl/WpBlt2, it displays all relevant information but misses description.

Can some one please advice what should be the solution.

Comment: Google+ generally only shows descriptions if you have no image thumbnail or if you use [Article rendering](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/article-rendering). The current image is too small for Article rendering.

Answer (score 0):

add a simple:

```
<meta name="description" content="your description..." />
```

google will take it into account

OR
use schema.org tags (don't forget to modify your html tag too)

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

<!-- Schema.org markup for Google+ -->
<meta itemprop="name" content="The Name or Title Here">
<meta itemprop="description" content="This is the page description">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
```

Comment: open graph uses `<meta property` not `<meta name` - as in his original code

Comment: @Mousey yes, the meta name is not open graph, but google does not parse only opengraph tags. Anyway i think that the correct answer is abraham comment below his question

Comment: @heidi I wasn't sure if `<meta name` was a mistake in your answer (if it is you can edit your answer). The schema markup only works if nested inside a tag with a scope, normally microdata goes in the body, see my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32782177/4258817